# import a reference in an aspx file without visual studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api, reference

I have a standalone aspx with vb.net backend file. I need to import google api referance in this file. If i put this file in a asp.net application project, the referance gets imported easily by using "add referance". But when i use a standalone file, the referance cannot be imported. 
How can i import this google api referance (or any referance) in an aspx file without having to make a project for it?

imports from google -
Imports Google.GData.Contacts
Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Extensions
Imports Google.Contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the top of the ASPX page:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Assembly's full name" %>
```

Comment: when you say Assembly's full name, should it be google.gdata? form the import samples i've posted above

Comment: @refeer: The DLL's filename, without `.dll`.

Comment: so basically something like this -

Comment: <%@ Assembly Name="Google.GData.Contacts" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Google.GData.Client" %> .. and so on?

Comment: Error Message its giving - Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.GData.Contacts' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @refeer:  Copy the DLL file to your bin folder.  You then might not need the `<%@ Assembly` declaration at all.